# Jenkins Pipeline Scripting - quick Run?

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and haven't really done any Groovy yet.

As it's mostly "trial and error" how to use Groovy and the Pipeline properly and looking at the results I find the general way of running the code it a little long. (Save --> Build now --> Console Output).

Is there a way of testing it more extensively? (For example within the Pipeline-Configuration itself?) It seems the Jenkins Scripting Console uses a different environment and I can't use it for testing the Pipeline-Codes.